# Linux: Chrome Cache Viewer

Tags: linux, google-chrome, browser-cache

[Chrome Cache View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html) exists for Windows. Does anything like this exist for Linux? It seems that `chrome://cache` no longer exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any linux-specific tool, but I was able to get Chrome Cache View to work on Linux using Wine. You just have to set the cache directory correctly. I used `Z:\home\myusername\.cache\google-chrome\Default\Cache\` and it worked!